# select specific col of a CSV file for tokenization

Tags: python, csv

I have a function that removes stopwords for each sentence in column B in a CSV file.
The CSV file has 5 columns.
Heres my code:

```
  with open(filename,"rU") as f:
    next(f)
    for row in f:
       token= row.split()
       .
       .
```

How do i only select the second column (column B) for tokenization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `csv` module instead of writing the mundane code yourself:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   next(reader)
   for row in reader:
      print(row[1])  # Column 'B'
```